# find closed form for recurrence relation using generating function. terminate exercise

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have this recurrence relation:

$$\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    a_{n+1} = a_n + n &  (n\geq0)\\
    a_0 = 0
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}$$

Set:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$

I have solved:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+1}x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^n$$
$$\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+1}x^{n+1} = f(x) + x \bigg( \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \bigg)$$
$$\frac{1}{x}f(x) = f(x) + \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} $$
$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{(1-x)^3}$$

So:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{(1-x)^3} = \frac{A}{1-x}+\frac{B}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{C}{(1-x)^3}$$

And:

$$\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    A = 1\\
    B = -2\\
C = 1
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}$$

So I have:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{(1-x)^3} = \frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{2}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}$$

How can I procede to get recurrence relation?

Comment: What is the question? The equation $a_{n+1}=a_n+n$ _is_ a recurrence relation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of  the fact that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{k+n-1}{n}x^n=\frac{1}{(1-x)^k}; \quad (k\geq 1, |x|<1)
$$
which can be obtained by repeatedly differentiating the geometric series or from the generalized binomial theorem. In any case (proceeding from where you left off)
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(1-2(n+1)+\binom{n+2}{2}\right)x^n
$$
whence
$$
a_n=1-2(n+1)+\binom{n+2}{2};\quad (n\geq
0).$$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, just a question. the binomial in the first sum, is it correct? shouldn't be $k$ at the bottom?